# Select from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am populating a List in my application. In a different Activity I'm trying to get every "event" to display in a ListView. Therefore I set up a EditText where I enter a city e.g "Hamburg". After the confirm button is clicked the list is supposed to show all the events in Hamburg.

```
+---------+----------+----------+------------------+
| user_id |   name   | location |   description    |
+---------+----------+----------+------------------+
|       5 | Dinner   | Hamburg  | With the Family  |
|       6 | Marriage | Bremen   | Alex and Sabrina |
|       7 | Match    | Berlin   | Hamburg - Hertha |
|       8 | Meeting  | Berlin   | Alexanderplatz   |
|       9 | Cinema   | Berlin   | FUG2             |
+---------+----------+----------+------------------+
```

My question, I cannot figure out how to state the SQL-Statement in the PHP document. All i have is:

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE location = ':location'") or die(mysql_error());
```

[image]

Comment: remove ':location' single quote and check

Comment: Where do you set `:location`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does `mysql_*` even have parameterised query support?

Comment: BTW: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Please copy-paste the text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_` functions are [depricated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). I don't think that original mysql extension supports named parameters. You really should look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or even better [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

In mysqli that would be something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE location = ?";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("s", $location);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting data to php file then you can use something like this for location :

```
$location=$_POST['location'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE location = $location") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE location = $location")
```